# javascript: using inheritance "as is"

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I want to use some very simple inheritance in Javascript without any libraries (jQuery, Prototype, etc.) and I'm forgetting how to do this.

I know how to create a simple non-inherited object:

```
function Foo(x)
{
    this.x = x;
}
Foo.prototype = {
    inc: function() { return this.x++; }
}
```

which I can then use as follows:

```
js>f1=new Foo(0)
[object Object]
js>f1.inc()
0
js>f1.inc()
1
js>f1.inc()
2
```

But how would I add a subclass with one additional method that inherits the Foo "inc" method, without changing the Foo class?

```
function Bar(x)
{
    this.x = x;
}
Bar.prototype = new Foo();
Bar.prototype.pow = function(y) { return this.x+"^"+y+"="+Math.pow(this.x,y); }
```

That seems right except for this weirdness with the constructor; I have to call the Foo constructor once to create the Bar prototype, and when Bar's constructor is called, it seems like there's no way to call the Foo constructor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In cases like these I tend to move the "constructor code" to an `init` function. Of course, you could use `apply` on the previous constructor (using the new `Bar` object as the context) as well to to mimic `base()` (C#) or `super()` (Java).

Comment: like this? it doesn't seem to work. `function Bar(x) { this.constructor.prototype.constructor.apply(this,[x]); }`

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instead of doing `new Foo()`. It will also create a new object inheriting from Foo.prototype but *without* calling the Foo constructor.

```
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

While Object.create might not be defined on older browsers, it is possible to define it yourself if you need to. (the following code is from the MDN link)

```
if (!Object.create) {  
    Object.create = function (o) {  
        if (arguments.length > 1) {  
            throw new Error('Object.create implementation only accepts the first parameter.');
            //tbh, the second parameter is for stuff you dont need right now.
        }  
        function F() {}  
        F.prototype = o;  
        return new F();  
    };  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. It does exactly what you do, which is the only way I know to inherit, but this function uses `create`, which is new in ECMAScritp 5, if it's available, and does some extra checking:

```
function inherit(p) {
if (p == null) throw TypeError(); // p must be non-null
if (Object.create) // If Object.create() is defined (ECMAScript 5 way)
return Object.create(p); // use it
var t = typeof p; // If not, do some more checking (the old way)
if (t !== "object" && t !== "function") throw TypeError();
function f() {}; // Define constructor
f.prototype = p; // Set prototype to p.
return new f(); // call constructor f() to create an "heir" of p
}
```